# PHP: unreadable output characters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding

I am working on a page with PHP but the data (text) I stored in my database while I retrieve it it is showing unreadable characters as you can see from my online instance.

http://www.taleemulislam-radio.com/test.php

and my PHP code for that page is:

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";

try {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `updated` DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
}

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ps">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>تعليم الاسلام راډيو</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?=var_dump($result)?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Sample:** http://www.taleemulislam-radio.com/test.php

Comment: I can't tell the readable from non-readable characters.

Comment: @chip no it is working well with our other pages from the same database and same table like: http://www.taleemulislam-radio.com/bashpar.php?id=5746 I think it is the problem with character-set or may be something else.

Comment: In phpMyAdmin change the collation of this table to Persian

Comment: @Aviz there is no Persian but it is set to utf8_unicode_ci.

Comment: There must me be one collation option that matches persian

Comment: @Aviz Can you provide that to me?

Comment: Try with "utf_persian_ci" . No need to change the whole database just the "content" table

Comment: @Aviz Thanks but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Sorry .. Well I tried .. Try to find if you match the <meta charset=""> for persian

Comment: @Aviz Thanks, I will try but I utf-8 character-set will work for all language characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag should be

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Set the charset attribute of the PDO dsn.

Declare you column(s) to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE content;` for verification.

Let's check what is stored.  Please do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...;` to see if you get mostly D8xx and D9xx, such as:

```
D8AAD8B9D984D98AD98520D8A7D984
```

If your "unreadable characters" are something like

```
ØªØ¹Ù„ÙŠÙ… Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… Ø±Ø§Ú‰ÙŠÙˆ
```

then you have the classic case of

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8.apostrophe.)
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  (It should have been `utf8`.)

The fix for the *data* is a "2-step ALTER".

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.